# Can Sobolev space be characterized by spectral decomposition?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces

Consider a homogeneous Carnot group $\mathbb{G}$ with step $r$. Let $X_1,\cdots,X_m$ be the first layer of its Lie algebra. Denote by $\mathcal{L}=-\sum_{i=1}^m X_i^2$ the sub-Laplacian on $\mathbb{G}$. (For ease, one can just consider $\mathbb{G}=\mathbb{R}^n$, $r=1$,  $X_i=\partial_{x_i}$, $m=n$ and $\mathcal{L}=-\Delta$ the classical Laplacian.) The associated Sobolev space is defined by
$$H^1(\mathbb{G}):=\{u\in L^2(\mathbb{G})| X_iu\in L^2(\mathbb{G}) \}$$
with the norm $\|u\|_{H}^2=\|u\|_{L^2(\mathbb{G})}^2+\sum_{i=1}^m\|X_iu\|_{L^2(\mathbb{G})}^2$, where $X_iu$ is understood in the distribution sense. On the other hand, one may self-adjoint extend $\mathcal{L}$ to be an operator on
$$\text{Dom}(\mathcal{L}):=\{u\in L^2(\mathbb{G})| \mathcal{L}u\in L^2(\mathbb{G})\}.$$
In this case, by spectral decomposition we have
$$\mathcal{L}=\int_0^\infty\lambda dE_\lambda.$$
**Can we have**
$$H^1(\mathbb{G})=\left\{u\in L^2(\mathbb{G})\Big| \int_0^\infty\lambda d \|E_\lambda u\|_{L^2(\mathbb{G})}^2<+\infty \right\}?$$

**reference:** I read the paper

> [Folland G B. Subelliptic estimates and function spaces on nilpotent Lie groups[J]. Arkiv för matematik, 1975, 13(1-2): 161-207.](http://archive.ymsc.tsinghua.edu.cn/pacm_download/116/7227-11512_2006_Article_BF02386204.pdf)

Let $\mathcal{L}_p$ be minus the infinitesimal generator of Heat semi-group $H_t$ on $L^p(\mathbb{G})$ (page 180). Theorem (3.8) gives a characterization between $\mathcal{L}_p$ and original $\mathcal{L}$.
In page 181, he define the fractional order of $\mathcal{L}_p$, i.e., $\mathcal{L}_p^\alpha$. In page 186, he define the Sobolev space ($\alpha\geq 0$, $1<p<\infty$) $S_\alpha^p:=\{u\in L^p(\mathbb{G})|\|\mathcal{L}^{\frac{\alpha}{2}}f\|_{L^p(\mathbb{G})}<+\infty\}$ with norm $\|u\|_{p,\alpha}^2=\|u\|_{L^p(\mathbb{G})}^2+\|\mathcal{L}^{\frac{\alpha}{2}}u\|_{L^p(\mathbb{G})}^2$. Now I want to apply Theorem (4.10) that says

> (4.10) Theorem. If $1<p<\infty$ and $\alpha \geq 0$, then $f \in S_{\alpha+1}^p$ if and only if $f$ and the distribution derivatives $X f$ are in $S_\alpha^p$ for all $X \in V_1$ (the first layer). The norms $\|f\|_{p, \alpha+1}$ and $\|f\|_{p, \alpha} +\sum_{j=1}^m\left\|X_j f\right\|_{p, \alpha}$ are equivalent.

by letting $p=2$ and $\alpha=0$ then we are done. But I'm not sure whether $\|\mathcal{L}^{\frac{\alpha}{2}}f\|_{L^p(\mathbb{G})}=\|\mathcal{L}_p^{\frac{\alpha}{2}}f\|_{L^p(\mathbb{G})}$ or not. On the other hand, I am nor sure whether
$$S_1^2=\left\{u\in L^2(\mathbb{G})\Big| \int_0^\infty\lambda d \|E_\lambda u\|_{L^2(\mathbb{G})}^2<+\infty \right\}$$
or not by the definition of $S_\alpha^p$.